# Is it possible to modify the URLScheme of iOS Application after compiling code?

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on, url-scheme

I am using two facebook applications to perform facebook connect with my iOS app(using different application for different region viz UK, US).

I am using SSO for facebook connect (FB SDK 3.1).
Now, I want to support third region without submitting new build to app store.
But for the same I have to configure URL Scheme that facebook application understand so it will open my iOS app(like: fbMY_FB_APP_ID).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will have to submit a new app to the appstore since you are going to change the `info.plist`

Comment: Yes, I am facing same issue, but is there any work around from FB side means if I configure my FB application differently, as they accept arrays of url scheme.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, the SSO check facebook app and that starts your app by the `fb<facebookAppId>` scheme.